# Resize image when resizes window

Tags: html, css, sass, less

everyone!

I guess my problem is simple, but I can't  figure out how to solve it :/

I would like to make an Image full height and full width, and when we resize the windows' width, the image resizes correctly like this example:
https://avada.theme-fusion.com/resume/

I already tried to play around with the width and height, but I can't have the same result

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Please include the html and css that you used, and the results you got, so we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you're looking for is `background-size: cover`.

```
body{
  background-image: url('https://avada.theme-fusion.com/resume/wp-content/uploads/sites/66/2016/07/home_bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

You'll need to use a css `background-image` instead of an `<img/>` to achieve this result.

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7rqm0mtb/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly that! Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be ideal if you could post the code you're working with in order to get a better understanding on how you're going about this.

The Avada link you posted is using the image as a background-image, with the background-size property set to 'cover'. Take a look at [this example on w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover).